# ValueFormatter throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a small problem. I'm trying to make a listView of BarCharts, where xAxis represents categories, and yAxis - cost.

Here is my data.
entry

```
entries.add(new BarEntry(xAxis, cost, categoryName));
```

xAxis is just a position in chart, I put category name as 3rd parameter. Then I put it in array list of BarData

```
ArrayList<BarData> months = new ArrayList<>(); 
BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, monthName);
ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(set);
BarData barData = new BarData(dataSets);
months.add(barData);
```

Then in adapter I set value formatter

```
BarData data = getItem(position);
...
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter(data.getDataSetByIndex(0)));
```

and in MyValueFormatter I'm trying to get category name from entry and set it as xAxis value.

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

private IBarDataSet mDataSet;

public StatisticByMonthValueFormatter(IBarDataSet data) {
    mDataSet = data;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    return (String) mDataSet.getEntryForIndex((int) value).getData();
}
}
```

This woks, but sometimes when I'm scrolling list view I get

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 2.
```

I know, that bug in the getFormattedValue method in MyValueFormatter, but i don't understand how can I fix this, or how implement this in the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataSet#getEntryForIndex(int index)`

is the wrong method to call here. `Entry` in a `DataSet` are stored in a backing array and this method will get the `Entry` at that index in the backing array. This doesn't always correspond to the `Entry` for that x-value (the x-value on the chart). Hence, the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You would want to do something this instead:

`return (String) mDataSet.getEntryXPos(float value).getData();`

See the [javadoc for DataSet](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.2/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/DataSet.html) for further explanation

Comment: Thanks for help, now it works fine. But in my version of MPChart there is no getEntryXPos method, instead of this I used getEntryForXValue.

Comment: @Alexandr I'm glad it solved your problem. Can you please accept the answer (green tick)